# How to replace or wrap a method argument by a new argument of same type using ASM Java bytecode library?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

There is a requirement in my project to replace or wrap a method argument by a new argument of same type.

For example,

```
public ArrayList doSubmit(java.lang.Runnable runnableObj){
 runnableObj = wrapObject(runnableObj);
 ........
}
```

I have to replace the `runnableObj` by another object which is also `java.lang.Runnable`

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: Hi Holger, Apologies for providing very minimal details. My question is - Changing method arguments reference (same type) is possible using ASM library ?

Comment: Yes, it’s possible.

Comment: How do you want to wrap it? Calling some method? Replace it with `null`? Can you [edit] your question add a line like `runnableObj = ...;` inside your example method?

Comment: Hi Johannes Kuhn, Need to wrap it by calling a method.

Comment: Ok, is the method static? Also, what is the class name that contains the method?

Comment: The `doSubmit(java.lang.Runnable runnableObj)` is not static & the class name of this method is `com.trace.async.Tracer`